# In postman how to limit access for team member to only specific workplace(s)?

Tags: postman

I am using the postman pro with a team of 5 members. 2 members are not of my company, but from a customer (project) we are working on. They are however member of our postman team. 
How can I limit their access in postman so that they can only see one workspace (for their project) and not other team workspaces (the other 3 team members are working on other projects as well)?